# How can I know if the user has closed the application from the background

Tags: background

How can I send certain data to the database in case the user killed off the app directly from background or if the app is minimized but haven't being killed yet so it's in background, how can I do that I would be very grateful to anyone giving me this information.
i am using flutter

```
if ( App is being killed OR in background mode??? Just an example of what is required )
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).update({
                                    
"AppStatus" : false

  });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help improve your question. As it stands currently, it is very hard to understand what you need. You haven't even included what framework/languages your app is built on, what devices the app runs on, among other things.

Comment: thank you so mush for telling me this advice , i will edit it and mention all what u said .